# Lognormal distribution inverse equivalent

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

In Lognormal distribution if the random variable X is log-normally distributed, then Y = ln(X) has a normal distribution.
Is there inverse equivalent to lognormal distribution where Y = exp(X) has a normal distribution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easily shown to be impossible for any real-valued random variable $X$:  if we require $$Y = e^X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2),$$ then there must be some value of $X$ for which $e^X < 0$.  But this is impossible if $X \in \mathbb R$.